# How modify Yii2 pagination in GridView widget to show first and last pages?

Tags: php, gridview, pagination, yii2

Default view of pagination is "1, 2, 3, ..., 10"

I need to transform it into "(first page), x, x, x, (current page), x, x, x, (last page)"

How can I do that?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'pager' => [
        'firstPageLabel' => 'First',
        'lastPageLabel'  => 'Last'
    ],
    ...
]) ?>
```

Comment: How it's different from my answer?

Comment: Your answer creates a new tag with the same functionality that the tag by default, but keeps the tag default, while my answer replaces the tag by default

Answer (score 23):

You need to specify [$firstPageLabel](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-linkpager.html#$firstPageLabel-detail) and [$lastPageLabel](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-linkpager.html#$lastPageLabel-detail) properties of [LinkPager](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-linkpager.html) (they are `false` by default meaning these links are not shown) . You can pass it to `GridView` like that:

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    ...
    'pager' => [
        'firstPageLabel' => 'First',
        'lastPageLabel' => 'Last',
    ],
    ...
]) ?>
```

For styling there are two additional properties: [$firstPageCssClass](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-linkpager.html#$firstPageCssClass-detail) and [$lastPageCssClass](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-linkpager.html#$lastPageCssClass-detail).

Note that you can apply this to `LinkPager` separately, without using `GridView`.

Comment: We should mention that it is not restricted on GridView widget. It may be applied to LinkPager widget too.

Comment: Yes, I but I already mentioned that these properties belongs to `LinkPager`. Added additional info according to your remark.

Answer (score 7):

Note since Yii2 version 2.0.11, you can set `firstPageLabel` and `lastPageLabel` defaults for the whole application using container definitions in your config/main.php file:

```
$config = [

    ....

    'container' => [
        'definitions' => [
            'yii\widgets\LinkPager' => [
                'firstPageLabel' => 'First',
                'lastPageLabel'  => 'Last'
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
```

Learn more at http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-configurations.html#application-configurations

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Bootstrap 4.x.x

```
'container' => [
   'definitions' => [
        \yii\widgets\LinkPager::class => \yii\bootstrap4\LinkPager::class,
        'yii\bootstrap4\LinkPager' => [
            'firstPageLabel' => 'First',
            'lastPageLabel'  => 'Last'
      ]
   ],
],
```